# Assign flag if successful retry within 1 second

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I am trying to assign flag to each entry in the data based on successful retry within 1 second. Here is the sample data

```
date       id  event            url  code  event_ts
2021-08-20 11  1629515037.0682  xyz  503   2021-08-20 20:03:57.068
2021-08-20 11  1629515037.1073  xyz  200   2021-08-20 20:03:57.107  -- successful retry within 1 sec
2021-08-20 12  1629515037.1866  abc  503   2021-08-20 20:03:57.187
2021-08-20 12  1629515037.1942  abc  503   2021-08-20 20:03:57.194
2021-08-20 12  1629515037.2037  abc  503   2021-08-20 20:03:57.204
2021-08-20 12  1629515037.2249  abc  503   2021-08-20 20:03:57.225
2021-08-20 12  1629515064.2427  abc  200   2021-08-20 20:04:24.243  -- successful retry within 1 sec
```

I want to create a new column retry where,

```
if code = 503, successful retry within 1 sec -> successful_retry
if code = 503, successful retry after 1 sec -> successful_retry_after_1_sec
if code = 503, no successful retry at all -> no_successful_retry
```

I am primarily a Python/Pandas person but need to solve this in presto. I tried using LEAD() but wan't able to write a solution with variable offset. Would appreciate pointers

Edit: Based on @Gordon Linoff's answer

```
SELECT
    date,
    id,
    url,
    event,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(event) AS event_ts,
    code,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN code <= 399 THEN 'successful_response'
            WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN code <= 399 THEN FROM_UNIXTIME(event) END) OVER (
                PARTITION BY
                    date,
                    id,
                    url
                ORDER BY
                    date,
                    id,
                    url,
                    event rows BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED following
            ) <= FROM_UNIXTIME(event) + INTERVAL '1' SECOND THEN 'success_retry_within_1_sec'
            WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN code <= 399 THEN FROM_UNIXTIME(event) END) OVER (
                PARTITION BY
                    date,
                    id,
                    url
                ORDER BY
                    date,
                    id,
                    url,
                    event rows BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED following
            ) > FROM_UNIXTIME(event) + INTERVAL '1' SECOND THEN 'success_retry_after_1_sec'
            ELSE 'No_successful_retry'
        END
    ) AS successful_retry_flag
FROM t
```

Comment: How do you know if a retry is successful?

Comment: oops, yeah successful retry is 200 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that 200 is a successful retry, you can get the next successful retry using a cumulative min.  The rest is date arithmetic to set the flag:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(case when code = 200 then event_ts end) over
                      (partition by id
                       order by event_ts
                       rows between current row and unbounded following
                      ) < event_ts + interval '1' second
             then 1 else 0
        end) as successful_retry_flag
from t;
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `event_ts` instead of `date` in `order by date` and `< date + interval '1' second`? And this includes only 2 out of the three cases, no?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I tweaked the above answer by adding order by id, event and < event_ts + interval '1' second and it works perfectly. Added full answer in the edit for the benefit of anyone referencing this in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can also accomplish this with a much more readable and extensible [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`](https://trino.io/blog/2021/05/19/row_pattern_matching.html) solution, which was added recently to Trino([formerly PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)).

With the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` solution you'll define your labels `success` and `failure` based on the value of `code` in current row being scanned. You can also define a measure of time between each row using the `MEASURES` clause to give you the `LAST` timestamp of the last successful row from the current failure timestamp which we can define as `time_to_success`. With these values defined via pattern matching, you can now filter them with the `CASE` statement much like @Gordon Linoff's solution.

```
trino> WITH t(date, id, event, url, code, event_ts) AS (VALUES
         ->     (DATE '2021-08-20', 11, 1629515037.0682, 'xyz', 503, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-20 20:03:57.068'),
         ->     (DATE '2021-08-20', 11, 1629515037.1073, 'xyz', 200, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-20 20:03:57.107'),
         ->     (DATE '2021-08-20', 12, 1629515037.1866, 'abc', 503, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-20 20:03:57.187'),
         ->     (DATE '2021-08-20', 12, 1629515037.1942, 'abc', 503, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-20 20:03:57.194'),
         ->     (DATE '2021-08-20', 12, 1629515037.2037, 'abc', 503, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-20 20:03:57.204'),
         ->     (DATE '2021-08-20', 12, 1629515037.2249, 'abc', 503, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-20 20:03:57.225'),
         ->     (DATE '2021-08-20', 12, 1629515064.2427, 'abc', 200, TIMESTAMP '2021-08-20 20:04:24.243')
         ->     )
         -> SELECT date, id, event, url, code, event_ts,
         ->        CASE
         ->            WHEN code = 200 THEN 'successful_response'
         ->            WHEN time_to_success < INTERVAL '1' SECOND THEN 'successful_retry'
         ->            WHEN time_to_success >= INTERVAL '1' SECOND THEN 'successful_retry_after_1_sec'
         ->            WHEN time_to_success IS NULL THEN 'no_successful_retry'
         ->        END flag
         -> FROM t
         -> MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
         ->     PARTITION BY id
         ->     ORDER BY event_ts
         ->     MEASURES FINAL LAST(success.event_ts) - failure.event_ts AS time_to_success
         ->     ALL ROWS PER MATCH WITH UNMATCHED ROWS
         ->     PATTERN (success* failure+ success)
         ->     DEFINE
         ->            success AS code = 200,
         ->            failure AS code = 503
         -> );
    date    | id |      event      | url | code |        event_ts         |             flag
------------+----+-----------------+-----+------+-------------------------+------------------------------
 2021-08-20 | 12 | 1629515037.1866 | abc |  503 | 2021-08-20 20:03:57.187 | successful_retry_after_1_sec
 2021-08-20 | 12 | 1629515037.1942 | abc |  503 | 2021-08-20 20:03:57.194 | successful_retry_after_1_sec
 2021-08-20 | 12 | 1629515037.2037 | abc |  503 | 2021-08-20 20:03:57.204 | successful_retry_after_1_sec
 2021-08-20 | 12 | 1629515037.2249 | abc |  503 | 2021-08-20 20:03:57.225 | successful_retry_after_1_sec
 2021-08-20 | 12 | 1629515064.2427 | abc |  200 | 2021-08-20 20:04:24.243 | successful_response
 2021-08-20 | 11 | 1629515037.0682 | xyz |  503 | 2021-08-20 20:03:57.068 | successful_retry
 2021-08-20 | 11 | 1629515037.1073 | xyz |  200 | 2021-08-20 20:03:57.107 | successful_response
(7 rows)
```